# Delphi - clearing ADO Tables

Tags: database, ms-access, delphi, delphi-xe2

So I've made a button in my program that's supposed to clear all the tables in my database but it gives an error when clicking on the button in run-time. How do I remove that error?

**Code I'm using:**

**ClearDB button's code**

```
procedure TfrmEntry.bmbClearDBClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  i:integer;
begin
  i:=MessageDlg('Are you sure you want to clear the Racers database? (all current data in the database will be lost.)',mtWarning,[mbOK,mbCancel],0);
  if i = mrOk then
  begin
    //clears entire database
    with dmRacers do
    begin
      tbl1660.DeleteRecords(arAll);
      tblXKarts.DeleteRecords(arAll);
      tblTwoPointOne.DeleteRecords(arAll);
      tblMidB.DeleteRecords(arAll);
      tblMidA.DeleteRecords(arAll);
      tblLateModel.DeleteRecords(arAll);
      tblSprints.DeleteRecords(arAll);
      tblV8.DeleteRecords(arAll);
      tblHeavyMetals.DeleteRecords(arAll);
      tblHotrods.DeleteRecords(arAll);
      tblPinkrods.DeleteRecords(arAll);
      tblStockrods.DeleteRecords(arAll);
      tblMinis.DeleteRecords(arAll);
      tblDevelopment.DeleteRecords(arAll);
    end;
  end
  else
  begin
    i:=MessageDlg('Clear aborted',mtInformation,[mbOk],0);
  end;
end;
```

**Entry button's code**

```
procedure TfrmEntry.btnEntryClick(Sender: TObject);
  var
  sRacerName,sLicence,sCarNum:string;
  iNum:integer;
begin
//saves input (works perfectly)
  sCarNum:=edtCarNumber.Text;
  sRacerName:=edtRacerName.Text;
  sLicence:=edtLicenseNum.Text;

            //ifs for saving input to the db
    if cbxGridSelect.Items[cbxGridSelect.ItemIndex] = '1660s' then
    begin
       with dmRacers do
       begin
          tbl1660.insert;
          tbl1660['Car Number']:=sCarNum;
          tbl1660['Racer Name']:=sRacerName;
          tbl1660['Licence']:=sLicence;
          tbl1660.Post;
       end;
    end
    else if cbxGridSelect.Items[cbxGridSelect.ItemIndex] = '2.1s' then
    begin
              with dmRacers do
       begin
          tblTwoPointOne.insert;
          tblTwoPointOne['Car Number']:=sCarNum;
          tblTwoPointOne['Racer Name']:=sRacerName;
         tblTwoPointOne['Licence']:=sLicence;
          tblTwoPointOne.Post;
       end;
    end
    else if cbxGridSelect.Items[cbxGridSelect.ItemIndex] = 'Crosskarts' then
    begin
              with dmRacers do
       begin
           tblXKarts.insert;
          tblXKarts['Car Number']:=sCarNum;
         tblXKarts['Racer Name']:=sRacerName;
          tblXKarts['Licence']:=sLicence;
          tblXKarts.Post;
       end;
    end
    else if cbxGridSelect.Items[cbxGridSelect.ItemIndex] = 'Heavy Metals' then
    begin
              with dmRacers do
       begin
           tblHeavyMetals.insert;
          tblHeavyMetals['Car Number']:=sCarNum;
         tblHeavyMetals['Racer Name']:=sRacerName;
          tblHeavyMetals['Licence']:=sLicence;
         tblHeavyMetals.Post;
       end;
    end
    else if cbxGridSelect.Items[cbxGridSelect.ItemIndex] = 'Hotrods' then
    begin
              with dmRacers do
       begin
        tblHotrods.insert;
          tblHotrods['Car Number']:=sCarNum;
         tblHotrods['Racer Name']:=sRacerName;
          tblHotrods['Licence']:=sLicence;
         tblHotrods.Post;
       end;
    end
    else if cbxGridSelect.Items[cbxGridSelect.ItemIndex] = 'Midgets A' then
    begin
               with dmRacers do
       begin
        tblMidA.insert;
          tblMidA['Car Number']:=sCarNum;
         tblMidA['Racer Name']:=sRacerName;
          tblMidA['Licence']:=sLicence;
         tblMidA.Post;
       end;
    end
    else if cbxGridSelect.Items[cbxGridSelect.ItemIndex] = 'Midgets B' then
    begin
               with dmRacers do
       begin
        tblMidB.insert;
          tblMidB['Car Number']:=sCarNum;
         tblMidB['Racer Name']:=sRacerName;
          tblMidB['Licence']:=sLicence;
         tblMidB.Post;
       end;
    end
    else if cbxGridSelect.Items[cbxGridSelect.ItemIndex] = 'Minis' then
    begin
               with dmRacers do
       begin
           tblMinis.insert;
          tblMinis['Car Number']:=sCarNum;
         tblMinis['Racer Name']:=sRacerName;
          tblMinis['Licence']:=sLicence;
          tblMinis.Post;
       end;
    end
    else if cbxGridSelect.Items[cbxGridSelect.ItemIndex] = 'Pinkrods' then
    begin
               with dmRacers do
       begin
           tblPinkrods.insert;
          tblPinkrods['Car Number']:=sCarNum;
         tblPinkrods['Racer Name']:=sRacerName;
          tblPinkrods['Licence']:=sLicence;
          tblPinkrods.Post;
       end;
    end
    else if cbxGridSelect.Items[cbxGridSelect.ItemIndex] = 'Sprints' then
    begin
               with dmRacers do
       begin
           tblSprints.insert;
          tblSprints['Car Number']:=sCarNum;
          tblSprints['Racer Name']:=sRacerName;
          tblSprints['Licence']:=sLicence;
          tblSprints.Post;
       end;
    end
    else if cbxGridSelect.Items[cbxGridSelect.ItemIndex] = 'Stockrods' then
    begin
               with dmRacers do
       begin
           tblStockrods.insert;
          tblStockrods['Car Number']:=sCarNum;
          tblStockrods['Racer Name']:=sRacerName;
          tblStockrods['Licence']:=sLicence;
          tblStockrods.Post;
       end;
    end
    else if cbxGridSelect.Items[cbxGridSelect.ItemIndex] = 'SWD Development' then
    begin
                with dmRacers do
       begin
          tblDevelopment.insert;
          tblDevelopment['Car Number']:=sCarNum;
          tblDevelopment['Racer Name']:=sRacerName;
          tblDevelopment['Licence']:=sLicence;
          tblDevelopment.Post;
       end;
    end
    else if cbxGridSelect.Items[cbxGridSelect.ItemIndex] = 'V8s' then
    begin
               with dmRacers do
       begin
          tblV8.insert;
          tblV8['Car Number']:=sCarNum;
          tblV8['Racer Name']:=sRacerName;
          tblV8['Licence']:=sLicence;
          tblV8.Post;
       end;
    end
    else if cbxGridSelect.Items[cbxGridSelect.ItemIndex] = 'Late Models' then
         begin
                  with dmRacers do
       begin
          tblLateModel.insert;
          tblLateModel['Car Number']:=sCarNum;
          tblLateModel['Racer Name']:=sRacerName;
          tblLateModel['Licence']:=sLicence;
          tblLateModel.Post;
       end;
         end;
  end;
```

**Data module's code**

```
   const
  scConnectionString = 'Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=%pathtomdb%Racers.mdb;Mode=ReadWrite;Persist Security Info=False;';

procedure TdmRacers.DataModuleCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
path:string;
begin
  path:=ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0));
  conToDB.ConnectionString := StringReplace(scConnectionString, '%pathtomdb%', path, []);
  conToDB.Connected:=True;
  tbl1660.Active := True;
  tblXKarts.Active := True;
  tblTwoPointOne.Active := True;
  tblMidB.Active := True;
  tblMidA.Active := True;
  tblLateModel.Active := True;
  tblSprints.Active := True;
  tblV8.Active := True;
  tblHeavyMetals.Active := True;
  tblHotrods.Active := True;
  tblPinkrods.Active := True;
  tblStockrods.Active := True;
  tblMinis.Active := True;
  tblDevelopment.Active := True;
end;
```

**Error I'm recieving:**
[image]

Thanks in advance for all the help!
Kind Regards
PrimeBeat

Comment: Always indicate on which source code line an error ultimately happens. That means, step into function/procedure calls until you find the code line that actually triggers the error. In the debugger you use `F8` to step over function/procedure calls and `F7` to step into them.

Comment: It takes me to line 87 of my code which is: `MyCmd.CommandText := 'Delete * from tbl1660';`

Comment: Good! So (with ref to your comment to the one answer you have got), is `MyCmd` nil? Maybe you did not realize that you need to create it, just like any object?

Comment: @TomBrunberg Well, I didn't think of that. What should I put between the parentheses in the `.Create()` command? Cause if I insert `nil` or `Self`, it still gives access violations?

Comment: In case you wrote e.g. `MyCmd.Create(nil)`, then that is wrong. The correct way would be `MyCmd := TADOCommand.Create(nil)`. But, let's take a step back. As you are using `ADO` I would expect that you have added a `TADOCommand` (named `ADOCommand1` as default) to your form. If you have done that, then you already have a command component and just replace `MyCmd` with `ADOCommand1` in the code from the answer you have got, as `ADOCommand1` will be automatically instantiated by the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a 2005 thread in borland.public.delphi.database.ado:

> http://www.devsuperpage.com/search/Articles.asp?ArtID=877427
>
> PROBLEM:
>
> I am trying to delete all records from a TADOTable. I am
> using the following line of code:
>
> tblInvoices.DeleteRecords(arAll);
>
> But it gives an error message: "Operation is not allowed in this
> context".
>
> Any idea what might be causing this?
>
> CAUSE:
>
> Unfortunately Microsoft never implemented that option for DeleteRecords.
> You will need to use a Delete query.
>
> SOLUTION:
>
> Instead of using the DeleteRecords, use a routine like this:
>
> ```
>     CabInfo.Active := true;
>
>     MyCmd.CommandText := 'Delete * from CabInfo';
>     MyCmd.Execute;
>
>     CabInfo.Active := false;
> ```
>
> where CabInfo is your table name.

Comment: It doesn't work, it gives an access violation error. I put it in a procedure and I used it just like you put in your answer but it only gives errors.

Comment: The specific error is "Access violation at address 0069C483 in module 'frmRacerEntry_p.exe'. Read of address 00000000". I'll add my code from the data module shortly, maybe I have a problem there that I'm not seeing.

Comment: @PrimeBeat AV with address zero or close to zero usually indicates attempt to access an object that is not yet created. Again, on which line of your code does the error occur?